# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I saw already some approaches but nothing which would solve my problem.

I create two entities, Shop and Article. Shop has the relationship "articles" and Article "shop", both are many to many and ordered relationships.

[image]

For the shop I have one CollectionViewController and for Articles TableViewController. After selecting one Shop I send it via segue to the ArticleTableViewController, where I can add Articles to the current shop.

**ArticleTableViewController**

```
var articles: [Article] = []
var currentShop: Shop?

@IBAction func pressAddButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let article = Article(context: managedContext!)
    article.name = "Milk"

    currentShop?.addToArticles(article)

    saveManagedContext()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

 func loadArticles () {

    let articleFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Article> = Article.fetchRequest()
    articleFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "shop = %@", currentShop!)

    do {
        articles = try managedContext.fetch(articleFetchRequest)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func saveManagedContext() {
    do {
        try managedContext?.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

If I build and run and select one shop, the app terminated with the reason:
**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'**

I think the problem is the predicate, because if I comment it out and run again and then select the shop it works fine, but all shops have the same articles that I added.

**How to fetch just the articles for the selected Shop?**

Comment: Your predicate needs to be more along the lines of shop relationship contains currentShop.

Comment: and what for predicate, some concretely example?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
 NSPredicate(format: "ANY shop = %@", currentShop!)
```

Or, alternatively, can you just use `currentShop.articles`? That will return a `Set`, which may not suit your purpose in this case, but... generally you can just follow relationships.

Comment: Thank you Dave, it works fine. Just before the ios 10, it works with my approach